# Is there any way to use p5.js in react native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, p5.js

I have found a p5 JS wrapper for react (react-p5-wrapper) . Is there any way to implement p5 in react native app too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no way at the moment.

I just checked the GitHub repo of p5.js and it uses DOM elements (like canvas) in its source code (for example https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/src/image/image.js).
React Native doesn't have a DOM, so that's not possible (except maybe using a WebView or jsdom, but what's the point using RN then?).

I think you'll have to wait till someone makes a fork especially for React Native.

Comment: Maybe you could check out Ionic, as its just a native web view application.